# Multiple onclick funtions under same conditional

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm making a calculator, and I want to stop any type of numeric input once the limit of digits has been reached, I understand I can put an if statement inside each onclick function, but I was wondering if theres a way to only let the program read a whole section of code under the right condition, something like this:

```
only proceed if (limit is true){ onclick function a; onclick function b; }
```

Thank you!

Comment: please post the relevant code that you've got so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a function to check the limit and pass it the handler to call if the limit is not met.
`onclick="checkLimit(handleClick)"`

checkLimit would then call the passed function only if the counter is < limit.

Comment: thanks man, I'm doing it with only pure js so i figured it is jus easier to put the is statemen inside the onclic functions, cheers